# python: Conditional value in line greater than statement

Tags: python, text, conditional-statements

Python beginner here. I have a text file that is sorted into columns:

```
 fields = line.split("\t")
```

I am trying to ask if any of the values in columns 3 to 23 are greater than 95. All the columns contain single floating numbers eg 94.522342 or 99.2321321. What I have so far seems not to be working:

```
    if (int(fields(3:23)) >= 95):
```

I think the problem is with the (3:23) portion, when I am trying to ask to check each column.

Any help greatly appreciated,
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems with your code: You are comparing a list to a number, which does not give a meaningful result.  And you are using `int()` to decode floating-point numbers – use `float()` instead:

```
if any(float(x) >= 95 for x in fields[3:23]):
```

Note that this will examine the fourth column (index 3) up to the 23rd column (index 22).  Adjust the slice as necessary.

Comment: I forgot to mention a couple of the columns contain the string 'XX' instead of a floating-point number. Is there an easy way to ignore these or convert them to zeros?

Comment: @user964689: Write your own conversion function along the lines `def my_float(x): try: return float(x); except ValueError: return 0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

its's `fields[3:23]` and this returns a list and you can't compare a list to an integer

as you're new to python I'll suggest use the for loop:

```
for x in fields[3:23]:
    if float(x)>=95:
        #do_something here
    else:
           #do something else
```

or a one liner will be:

`if max(map(float,fields[3:23]))>=95`

Comment: `int("94.522342")` -> `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '94.522342'`. Better use `float()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`any` builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#any):

```
if any(map(lambda x: float(x) >= 95, fields[3:23])):
```

We do several things:

1. retrieve the correct columns with a slice operator
2. map all these values to a boolean (testing the float() against 95)
3. check that all results of the test are True.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want any value, try:

```
if max(fields[3:23]) > 95:
```

Comment: This assumes the values are numbers already; the post seems to suggest they are strings.

Comment: You would need to convert the fields to floating point numbers: `max(map(float, fields[3:23]))`.  Otherwise, nice idea!  The downside is that this approach cannot short-cut, as `any()` would do once it found a number greater than 95.

Comment: Small nitpick: the OP wants greater than *or equal to* 95.